# How to set margin top in each PDF page(generated) using JSPDF

Tags: jquery, pdf, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I am adding a plain text and an image logo as a header in pdf using JSPDF.
The first page works fine but on the second page of the generated pdf, the HTML content and my header both are overlapping. I need to give some margin for the content coming from HTML so that header and HTML content could be separate.

```
var imgData = "data:image/jpeg;base64" + "," + base64Data;
var pdf = new jsPDF("l", "mm", "legal");
var source = $('#HTMLtoPDF')[0];

var specialElementHandlers = {
  '#skipForPDFReport': function (element, renderer) {
    return true
  }
};

var margins = {
  top: 40,
  bottom: 60,
  left: 40,
  width: 200,
};

pdf.fromHTML(
  source // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
  , margins.left // x coord
  , margins.top // y coord
  , {
    'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF,

    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers,
    style: {
      fontSize: 5
    }
  },
  function (dispose) {
    var totalPages  = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
    console.log("total", totalPages);
    for(var i = totalPages; i >= 1; i--)
    { //make this page, the current page we are currently working on.
        pdf.setPage(i);                         
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 37, 10, 35, 20);
        pdf.setFont("helvetica");
        pdf.setFontType("bold");
        pdf.setFontSize(22);
        pdf.setTextColor("#38a4ff");
        pdf.text(175, 22, name + " - " + "Report", "center");
        pdf.setFontType("normal");
        pdf.setFontSize(12);
        pdf.text(180, 30, "Report generated on " + Moment().format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a") + " by " + userName, 'center');
        pdf.setTextColor("black");

    }
    // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF
    // this allow the insertion of new lines after html
    pdf.save('report.pdf');
  }
)
```

Comment: pages start with index i =0, from i > 1,  for addImage x coord is 37, margin is 40,so there is a chance of overlap

Comment: @NagaSaiA Thanks for your answer. When I change the margin of header it's getting impact but the margin for HTML content is only impacting for the first page of pdf rest page is getting render without having any top margin.

Comment: @Amit Did you get any solution so far ?